# TSQL XML Parsing / Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am passing XML to my stored procedure and inserting it into a table. If I am passing multiple nodes, is all of that happening before it gets to the `Something Else` comment?

For example, if my XML contained 6 vehicle nodes, this insert statement will run 6 times. Do all of those run before reaching the `something else` line?

The reason I ask is because I want to insert data from this XML into a separate table as well using the lastInsertedID from the code below.

Can this be done?

```
INSERT INTO licensePlates (carColor, carModel, licensePlate, empID, dateAdded)
                SELECT  ParamValues.x2.value('color[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                        ParamValues.x2.value('model[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                        ParamValues.x2.value('licensePlate[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                        @empID,
                        GETDATE()
                FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS ParamValues(x2) 

                --Something else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All 6 Rows will be INSERTed before the code hits `-- something else` line.

So if you want to capture all 6 IDs and INSERT those into some Audit Table or Foreign Key table, use the INSERTED table like so.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable_Audit 
(LastInsertedID, .....)    
SELECT ID, ....
FROM INSERTED;
```

*(Pseudocode, but you get the idea.)*

Comment: The issue im running into is I need to pass something from the XML I send to this new table as well. For example. It adds plate 1234 to the table and gets the ID of 1. I then need to add plate 1234 to table 2 with the plateID of 1 to reference that. How can I get the last ID for a specific node to make sure it matches in the new table ?